# How would I get UIImages to save in a collectionView using CoreData?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, uicollectionview

Im saving `UIImages` using Coredata. They appear in my collectionView but the problem Im having is that when I close my app and go back into the collectionView it is empty. How would I get the images to save in the collectionView? I know the images are saving because I checked the DataBase File Path and it shows all the images that are saved. Just can't figure out how to retrieve all the images once the app is closed and opened again. Thank you!

```
    let combineImages = mergedImageWith(frontImage: mainImage.image!, backgroundImage: backgroundImageView.image)
    
    // This is used to save every-time I press the button 
    if let png = combineImages.pngData() {
    DataBaseHelper.instance.saveImageInCoredata(imagData: png)
   
   } 

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell


    //cell.cellImage.image = self.arrImage[indexPath.row]
   
    let arr = DataBaseHelper.instance.getAllImages()
    cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(data: arr[indexPath.row].saveImages!)!

    print(arr.count)
    return cell
    
  }
 }

class DataBaseHelper: UIViewController {

static let instance = DataBaseHelper()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext    

func saveImageInCoredata(imagData: Data) {
    let photo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Photo", into: context) as! Photo
    photo.saveImages = imagData

do{
    try context.save()
}catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


func getAllImages() -> [Photo] {
    var arrPhotos = [Photo]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Photo")
    
    do {
        arrPhotos = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Photo]
        
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return arrPhotos
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't save images in the collection view, your current approach is correct to save data in CoreData and display it in a collection view. I believe you need to add breakpoints to a few places to see where the issue could be. For example, when do you call `getAllImages()` ? You should add a break point to `return arrPhotos in getAllImages()` and review if `arrPhotos` actually retrieves photos. What is the count in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` ? What do you do differently in the situation where images show in the collection view. Try these and update with your findings.

Comment: Im calling the `getAllImages` in the `cellForItem` I think I have to call it in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: yes, it should be at the start

Comment: Okay it ended up working I called the `getAllImages` in the `cellForItem` still. But what made it work was to use `arr.count` in the `numberOfItemsInSection`

Comment: nicely done, good to know you solved it.